# How to fill in the range of cells on the bottom of the data with "x" value

Tags: vba

The problem I am facing is this: I can't construct a code that would go to the bottom of the data in column A (data in A grows constantly so the code needs to always look for the `lRow`) and that would fill in all blank cells (which are not fixed and are changing whenever I update the data) e.g. in `lRow` between `A:G` with value "x".

Thank you

Comment: find last used row in columns A:G and use that as your last row variable and the [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)  etc to target the blank cells in that row between columns A and G and assign the value "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FillCells()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rng as Range, cl as Range

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A" & lastRow & ":G" & lastRow)

    For each cl in rng
        If cl = "" Then
           cl = "x"
        End if
    Next cl
End Sub
```

The code finds the next blank cell in column A and fills that row from columns A to G with the value "x".

Comment: Hi Alex, at the moment the code finds last value in "A" and adds a full row of "x's" below it. The thing is that e.g. while A is always populated, the cells next to it may not be, and whenever there is a blank I need it to be filled (blank in lastrow where A is populated).

Comment: Brilliant Alex! It works perfectly! That's what I needed :)

Answer (score -1):

use lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row.offset(1,0)
lastRow.value="c
that will gi